# How to dynamically reorder columns of a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I create the simple dataframe `tmp` for example purposes by running the Example Code 1 shown at the bottom. The actual dataframe this example is intended for has many columns and is dynamic, with the number of and calculations of columns dependent on user inputs. The below example is not dynamic for the sake of simplicity, although Example Code 2 shows the results of the dynamic addition of a column.

Running the Example Code 1 as drafted gives me a dataframe with columns ordered as:

```
> names(tmp)
[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"  "Sepal.calc1" 
[7] "Petal.calc1"  "Sepal.calc2"  "Petal.calc2"
```

When, instead, as a rule, I would like my `mutuate()` created column "Sepal.calc1" to always follow the last of the columns that begin with "Sepal..." (which is Sepal.Width in this static example) and I would like my created column "Sepal.calc2" to always follow "Sepal.calc1"; and I would like my created column "Petal.calc1" to always follow the last of the columns that begin with "Petal..." (which is Petal.Width in this static example) and I would like my created column "Petal.calc2" to always follow "Petal.calc1". I would like to do this without touching the order of the `mutate()` statements for other reasons not obvious in this example, preferring to do it with a `select()` function or some other function executed after all the mutates. If this `tmp` were a static dataframe I would simply run something static like:

```
%>% select(
    "Sepal.Length",
    "Sepal.Width",
    "Sepal.calc1",
    "Sepal.calc2",
    "Petal.Length",
    "Petal.Width",
    "Petal.calc1",
    "Petal.calc2",
    "Species"
    )
```

But that won't work because for example, there could be new columns added like Sepal.Width1, Sepal.Width.KooKoo, Petal.Width100, etc., interjected into the above `tmp` dataframe.

So how can I dynamically order the dataframe columns?

Example Code 1:

```
tmp <- iris[1:10,] %>%
  mutate(Sepal.calc1 = Sepal.Length * Sepal.Width,
         Petal.calc1 = Petal.Length * Petal.Width) %>%
  mutate(Sepal.calc2 = Sepal.calc1 * Sepal.Length,
         Petal.calc2 = Petal.calc1 * Petal.Length) %>%
  %>% select(
    "Sepal.Length",
    "Sepal.Width",
    "Sepal.calc1",
    "Sepal.calc2",
    "Petal.Length",
    "Petal.Width",
    "Petal.calc1",
    "Petal.calc2",
    "Species"
    )
tmp
```

Example Code 2 where new column dataframes are added, "as if" a user input triggered an expansion of the dataframe (note the addition of Sepal.Width1 and Sepal.Width1; under a dynamic user input the appended digit could be any number, not only a "1"):

```
tmp <- iris[1:10,] %>%
  mutate(Sepal.Width1 = Sepal.Width + 1) %>%
  mutate(Petal.Width1 = Petal.Width + 1) %>%
  select("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Sepal.Width1","Petal.Length","Petal.Width","Petal.Width1") %>%
  mutate(Sepal.calc1 = Sepal.Length * Sepal.Width,
         Sepal.calc2 = Sepal.calc1 * Sepal.Length
         ) %>%
  mutate(Petal.calc1 = Petal.Length * Petal.Width, 
         Petal.calc2 = Petal.calc1 * Petal.Length
         ) 

tmp
```

Comment: I'd do all the calculations, then use regex to reorder columns, something like: `cbind(cols starting with sepal, cols starting with sepal with calc, cols starting with petal, cols starting with petal with calc, other cols)`.

Comment: Works with the posted examples but in the actual code this is intended for there are many other columns whose positions are fine as the code works through the mutates, but there are only a few columns that have to be reordered/injected into the dataframe. There are so many columns doing a `cbind()` would be clumsy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code with `.after` parameter in mutate

```r
tmp <- iris[1:10,] %>%
  mutate(Sepal.calc1 = Sepal.Length * Sepal.Width,
         Sepal.calc2 = Sepal.calc1 * Sepal.Length, 
         .after=Sepal.Width) %>%
  mutate(Petal.calc1 = Petal.Length * Petal.Width, 
         Petal.calc2 = Petal.calc1 * Petal.Length,
         .after=Petal.Width) 

tmp
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Sepal.calc1 Sepal.calc2
1           5.1         3.5       17.85      91.035
2           4.9         3.0       14.70      72.030
3           4.7         3.2       15.04      70.688
4           4.6         3.1       14.26      65.596
5           5.0         3.6       18.00      90.000
6           5.4         3.9       21.06     113.724
7           4.6         3.4       15.64      71.944
8           5.0         3.4       17.00      85.000
9           4.4         2.9       12.76      56.144
10          4.9         3.1       15.19      74.431
   Petal.Length Petal.Width Petal.calc1 Petal.calc2
1           1.4         0.2        0.28       0.392
2           1.4         0.2        0.28       0.392
3           1.3         0.2        0.26       0.338
4           1.5         0.2        0.30       0.450
5           1.4         0.2        0.28       0.392
6           1.7         0.4        0.68       1.156
7           1.4         0.3        0.42       0.588
8           1.5         0.2        0.30       0.450
9           1.4         0.2        0.28       0.392
10          1.5         0.1        0.15       0.225
   Species
1   setosa
2   setosa
3   setosa
4   setosa
5   setosa
6   setosa
7   setosa
8   setosa
9   setosa
10  setosa
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort the data frame dynamically you can use `tmp %>% relocate(sort(names(.)))` or `tmp %>% select(sort(names(.)))`. This will sort the columns alphabetically:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

# Your provided data
tmp <- iris[1:10,] %>%
  mutate(Sepal.Width1 = Sepal.Width + 1) %>%
  mutate(Petal.Width1 = Petal.Width + 1) %>%
  select("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Sepal.Width1","Petal.Length","Petal.Width","Petal.Width1") %>%
  mutate(Sepal.calc1 = Sepal.Length * Sepal.Width,
         Sepal.calc2 = Sepal.calc1 * Sepal.Length
  ) %>%
  mutate(Petal.calc1 = Petal.Length * Petal.Width, 
         Petal.calc2 = Petal.calc1 * Petal.Length
  )

# Original order
tmp %>% names()
#>  [1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Sepal.Width1" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width" 
#>  [6] "Petal.Width1" "Sepal.calc1"  "Sepal.calc2"  "Petal.calc1"  "Petal.calc2"

# Fixed order 1
tmp %>% relocate(sort(names(.))) %>% names
#>  [1] "Petal.calc1"  "Petal.calc2"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Petal.Width1"
#>  [6] "Sepal.calc1"  "Sepal.calc2"  "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Sepal.Width1"

# Fixed order 2
tmp %>% select(sort(names(.))) %>% names()
#>  [1] "Petal.calc1"  "Petal.calc2"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Petal.Width1"
#>  [6] "Sepal.calc1"  "Sepal.calc2"  "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Sepal.Width1"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>